# googletest move constructor coverage

Tags: c++, googletest, gcovr

I am using `googletest` in conjunction with `gcovr` which is producing some odd behavior. I have a header file `foo.h` that `gcovr` claims has some lines that are not being covered under a test. These lines are the class definition and the move constructor:

```cpp
File  Lines Exec Cover Missing
foo.h 42    40   95%   39,47
```

Where line 39 is:

```cpp
class foo
```

and line 47 is:

```cpp
foo(foo&&) = default;
```

I have tried explicitly calling this function in a test body with `std::move()`, to no avail. Is there a solution to this problem, or am I stuck with a 99% coverage report?

I should note, there is no implementation in this header apart from the class definition and the copy/move semantics (which are all defined as `default`); all function bodies are in `foo.cpp`.

Comment: Have you tried such test code: `Foo foo1; Foo foo2(std::move(foo1));` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz Yes, I have tried calling that explicitly in a test case

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only way to get these lines to be removed from the coverage report as "uncovered" is to remove them from the header. This does not really affect anything since they are just setting copy/move/dtor to `default`. Everywhere else where these are actually implemented or deleted does not show up on the coverage report.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude some lines from the coverage calculation with special comments. This behaviour is undocumented, but stable. You can:

- exclude a line that contains `GCOVR_EXCL_LINE`
- exclude a region of lines between `GCOVR_EXCL_START` and `GCOVR_EXCL_STOP`.

The marker can start with `GCOVR` or `LCOV` in case you are using that tool as well. Lcov's branch exclusion markers are not currently supported.